# how to plot a data frame into R

Tags: r, printing, plot, dataframe

I have a txt filde in which is storedthe information related tu clusters:

```
PID   Cluster
123    1
234    1
2345   2 
......
```

I can read the field and then, I've generated a data frame. I want to plot the data in bars, that indicates for example the number of patients in y axe and the cluster in x axe. 
In this case I want two bars with values 2 and 1 respectively.
Thank you

Comment: `attach(yourDataFrame)`


`barplot(table(Cluster))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R:

```
patients = data.frame(PID = c(123, 234, 2345), Cluster = c(1,1,2))
pat.table = with(patients, table(Cluster))
barplot(pat.table)
```

Using ggplot2

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(patients, aes(x = factor(Cluster))) + geom_bar() + scale_x_discrete("Cluster")
```